# Uninstall / remove RPM

Tags: linux, uninstall, centos, rpm

I've installed CentOS 5 on an old IBM ThinkPad. Everything went fine until I had to make the wireless network connection work.

After searching Google I realise that I need to install RPM. Unfortunately I downloaded and installed the RPM for CentOS 3 - now when I try to reinstall the correct package for version 5, it says:

> File xxx from install of *rpmv5* conflicts with the file from package *rpmv3*

How can I rollback the RPM v3 installation? I've tried `rpm -e` without any success.

The RPMs can be found at: http://rpmforge.sw.be/redhat/

Comment: Post the full message please.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using CentOS, you may have yum from my knowledge.

I would try the following:

```
$ su -c 'yum remove packageNameHere'
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

```
rpm -e --nodeps
```

or

```
rpm --force -e
```

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS I find it best to use Yum - which, by default, should install the correct version from the CentOS repositories.

If you installed the wrong version using `rpm` I would also use the `rpm` command to uninstall it if possible (then try using Yum to install the correct version - if available in centOS repositories).

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade the existing package you could try:

```
rpm -U
```

Answer (score 0):

Great. How on earth did you install an outdated package like that?! Besides, RPM must have been installed on your system originally (it is the package manager, responsible for installing stuff and such). I fear you broke the system beyond (easy) repair.

You could try starting the system from a rescue/installation CD/DVD, and use "rpm --root=/where/your/system/is" to erase the outdated rpm (or "-U --force" the new one), cleanup the resulting mess ("package-cleanup" from the yum-utils package should help), perhaps do a "rpm --rebuilddb" for luck, cross your fingers that nothing got damaged permanently.

Before doing anything **read the relevant manuals, plan ahead, perhaps print the manuals out for reference while doing open-heart surgery on the system**.

Good luck!